# Which glass encapsulated component is this?

Tags: power-supply, components, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer this Chinese power supply and I came across this component:

Here it is on the circuit board:

[image: Component on the PCB]

And here's a close-up:

[image: the component]

It has a glass packaging, similar to a diode but it isn't polarised. It also has a red strip on the middle.

At first I thought it was a thermistor, then I tried measuring it's resistance while applying heat but it didn't change (always open loop).

Comment: Might be a ceramic capacitor.  Those are not common in glass, however.

Answer (score 24):

It is most likely a low-voltage low-current glass gas discharge (GGD) tube. It will not conduct at all until a certain voltage is reached, then the gas ionizes and it become effectively a short circuit until the current is removed. This small size is to suppress back-EMF, that is short-term low-current pulses. These devices can have capacitance values as low as 1.5 pf, making them useful in RF and microwave circuits to about 2 GHZ (in an smd package). For higher currents Transzorbs or MOV's would be used.

**EDIT 1**: Glass gas discharge (GGD) tubes are sensitive to fast rising or falling voltages. Rise and/or fall times less than 10uS can cause the gas in the tube to ionize quickly, at a voltage much lower than expected. It is a great idea to read all the fine details of a GGD before using them. In some cases such as back-EMF the fast rise time is an advantage, as the GGD will clamp it at a lower voltage than its normal slow rise-time clamp voltage.

**EDIT 2**: This could also be a tiny Transzorb. They are much like back-to-back zener diodes but can only handle brief burst of low currents. Transzorbs are not meant to be voltage regulators.

Comment: The G1 and G2 reference designators on the board sure are a big hint as to a gas discharge device.

Comment: @MichaelKaras. Agreed. I took those as a clue myself, and saw nothing to contradict that assumption. The "Tranzorb" comment was just to 'cover all the bases'.

Comment: Transzorbs is news for me.... Used to know TVS for years but not transzorbs.

Comment: @soosaisteven. Thanks for pointing out the typo-and I worked with them for 15 years...